# What's the difference between include_tasks and import_tasks?

Tags: ansible

In Ansible 2.4, the `include` module is deprecated. In its place, it ships with two replacement modules, `import_tasks` and `include_tasks`. But they have very similar descriptions:

- `include_tasks`: Includes a file with a list of tasks to be executed in the current playbook.
- `import_tasks`: Imports a list of tasks to be added to the current playbook for subsequent execution.

When should I use the former, and when should I use the latter?

Comment: (Also: the deprecation warning refers to "dynamic" and "static" tasks. I read the docs but didn't understand them.)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

There's quite a bit about this topic in the documentation:

- [Includes vs. Imports](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/playbooks_reuse_includes.html#includes-vs-imports)
- [Dynamic vs. Static](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/playbooks_reuse.html#dynamic-vs-static)

The main difference is:

> All `import*` statements are pre-processed at the time playbooks are parsed.
>   All `include*` statements are processed as they encountered during the execution of the playbook.

So `import` is static, `include` is dynamic.

From my experience, you should use `import` when you deal with logical "units". For example, separate long list of tasks into subtask files:

main.yml:

```
- import_tasks: prepare_filesystem.yml
- import_tasks: install_prerequisites.yml
- import_tasks: install_application.yml
```

But you would use `include` to deal with different workflows and take decisions based on some dynamically gathered facts:

install_prerequisites:

```
- include_tasks: prerequisites_{{ ansible_os_family | lower }}.yml
```

Comment: I found this link very useful: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_conditionals.html#applying-when-to-roles-imports-and-includes
It calls out a case where import and include behave differently - a 'when' conditional where the tasks in the file may change the criteria used to determine the import. With import_tasks, each task checks the criteria, so the behavior changes when the criteria changes. With include_tasks, the tasks are either present or not based on whether or not the condition was evaluated as true when the include_tasks statement was executed. If I understand well...

Comment: What was the behavior of `include`? If we were using `include` would `import_tasks` be the equivalent?

Comment: `include` had `static: yes` (behaved like `import_tasks`), and `static: no` (like `include_tasks`).

Comment: What is the default for `static`?

Comment: `static` is `None` by default: _Since Ansible 2.0, task includes are dynamic and behave more like real tasks. This means they can be looped, skipped and use variables from any source. Ansible tries to auto detect this, but you can use the static directive (which was added in Ansible 2.1) to bypass autodetection._

Comment: So should one default to using `import_tasks` where it would otherwise not make any difference?

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez I've been using `import_tasks` since asking this question, and it's been fine.

Comment: As docs structure and links in Ansible are ever changing :/ new link with docs mentioned by @EthelEvans is: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-with-re-use

Comment: So the `static` vs. `dynamic` refers to the composition of the task file name? Hardcoded yml file name (static) vs. composed file name based on variables (dynamic). Having a when condition doesn't make it dynamic, right? So if the file to include is just a hardcoded `tasks.yml` but followed by `when: somevar` then it's still static, not dynamic?

Answer (score 53):

Imports are static, includes are dynamic. Imports happen at parsing time, includes at runtime.

Imports basically replace the task with the tasks from the file. There are no import tasks at runtime. So, attributes like `tags`, and `when` (and most likely the rest) are copied to every imported task.

includes are indeed executed. `tags` and `when` of an included task apply only to the task itself.

Tagged tasks from an imported file get executed if an import task is untagged. No tasks is executed from an included file if an include task is untagged.

All tasks from an imported file get executed if an import task is tagged. Only tagged tasks from an included file get executed if an include task is tagged.

Limitations of imports:

- can't be used with `with_*` or `loop` attributes
- can't import a file, which name depends on a variable

Limitations of includes:

- `--list-tags` doesn't show tags from included files
- `--list-tasks` doesn't show tasks from included files
- you cannot use `notify` to trigger a handler name which comes from inside a dynamic include
- you cannot use `--start-at-task` to begin execution at a task inside a dynamic include

More on it [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html) and [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html).

For me that basically comes down to the fact that imports can't be used with the `loop` attribute.

imports would certainly fail in cases like [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#applying-when-to-roles-imports-and-includes):

```
# playbook.yml
- import_tasks: set-x.yml
  when: x is not defined

# set-x.yml
- set_fact
  x: foo
- debug:
  var: x
```

`debug` is not executed, since it inherits `when` from the `import_tasks` task. So, no importing task files that change variables used in the import task's `when` attribute.

I had a policy to start with imports, but once I needed an include I made sure nothing is imported by the included file or its children. But that's pretty damn hard to maintain. And it's still not clear if it'll protect me from troubles. I mean, mixing includes and imports is not recommended.

I can't use only imports, since I occasionally need loops. I could probably switch to only includes. But I decided to switch to imports everywhere except for the cases where I need loops. I decided to experience all those tricky edge cases first-hand. Maybe there won't be any in my playbooks. Or hopefully I'll find a way to make it work.

**UPD** A possibly useful trick to create a task file that can be imported many times, but *executed only once*:

```
- name: ...
  ...
  when: not _file_executed | default(False)

- name: ...
  ...
  when: not _file_executed | default(False)

...

- name: Set _file_executed
  set_fact:
    _file_executed: True
```

**UPD** One not really expected effect of mixing includes and imports is that an include task's vars override the ones of the imported tasks:

`playbook.yml`:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - import_tasks: 2.yml
      vars:
        v1: 1
    - include_tasks: 2.yml
      vars:
        v1: 1
```

`2.yml`:

```
- import_tasks: 3.yml
  vars:
    v1: 2
```

`3.yml`:

```
- debug:
    var: v1    # 2 then 1
```

Probably, because `include_tasks` first imports the files, and then applies its `vars` directive.

Actually, it can also be reproduced like so:

`playbook.yml`:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - import_tasks: 2.yml
      vars:
        v1: 1
    - include_tasks: 2.yml
      vars:
        v1: 1
```

`2.yml`:

```
- debug:
    var: v1    # 2 then 1
  vars:
    v1: 2
```

**UPD** Another case of mixing includes and imports.

`playbook.yml`:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    # say, you're bound to use include here (because you need a loop)
    - include_tasks: 2.yml
      vars:
        https: yes
```

`2.yml`:

```
- import_tasks: 3.yml
  when: https
```

`3.yml`:

```
- import_tasks: 4.yml
  vars:
    https: no  # here we're trying to temporarily override the https var
- import_tasks: 4.yml
```

`4.yml`:

```
- debug:
    var: https
```

We get `true` and `true`, see the previous case (`include_tasks`' vars take precedence over `import_tasks`' ones). To avoid that we can switch to includes in `3.yml`. But then the first include in `3.yml` is skipped. Since it inherites `when: https` from the parent task, so the first task basically reads:

```
- import_tasks: 4.yml
  vars:
    https: no  # here we're trying to temporarily override the https var
  when: https
```

The solution is to switch to includes in `2.yml` as well. That prevents propagation of `when: https` to the child tasks.

Comment: Great answer!. I was frustrated with everyone on the internet just repeating what the documentation says. Thank you.

Comment: Sergio Acosta exactly - ultimate answer is import is static and include dynamic like it should explain you anything about how it works :-P

Comment: i think i'm going includes by default, which most of my code is.  there are some modules i have that are open source (e.g. ansible-consul) that use imports for their handlers, and even some tasks with a when condition, then other open source (ansible-nomad) that use imports, so im not sure if that qualifies mixing or not, since they are each different roles, does it?

Comment: @BrianThomas I guess importing a file that uses `include`s or vice versa qualifies as mixing. As long as you don't do that, you should be safe.